# R subsetting rows where values in multiple columns don't match

Tags: r

Apologies if this has been asked already, but I searched and could not find an exact example of what I am trying to do.  I'm trying to subset a dataframe to exclude rows that have matching numerical values across five columns.  For example, for the following dataframe, df, I'd want to return a new dataframe only with rows 1:2, 5:6, and 8:10:

```
Row A   B   C   D   E
1   1   1   2   3   1
2   4   1   2   3   5
3   2   2   2   2   2
4   5   5   5   5   5
5   4   4   2   3   4
6   2   1   3   5   2
7   3   3   3   3   3
8   3   2   5   3   3
9   2   1   2   2   4
10  3   3   3   2   3
```

I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this for more than two columns.  I've tried the following and know they are not right.

```
df2 <- df[!duplicated(df, c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"))]
```

and

```
df2 <- df[df$A==df$B==df$C==df$D==df$E,]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Data frames are usually operated on column-wise rather than row-wise, which is why your `duplicated` attempt doesn't work. (It's checking for duplicate rows within those columns.) And your `==` doesn't work because `==` is a binary operator, `df$A == df$B` will be TRUE or FALSE, and then `(df$A == df$B) == df$C` (implied parentheses) will be testing if `df$C` is TRUE or FALSE.

`apply` is a good way to run a function on each *row*. It will convert your data frame to a matrix to run the function, but in this case that's fine columns A through E are all numeric. Here's one way:

```
df[apply(df[, -1], 1, function(x) length(unique(x))) > 1, ]
#    Row A B C D E
# 1    1 1 1 2 3 1
# 2    2 4 1 2 3 5
# 5    5 4 4 2 3 4
# 6    6 2 1 3 5 2
# 8    8 3 2 5 3 3
# 9    9 2 1 2 2 4
# 10  10 3 3 3 2 3
```

You could come up with all sorts of different functions to `apply` to test for all the elements being the same.

I assumed you actually have a column named `Row`. If that isn't the case, leave out the `-1` in my code above.

---

Using this data, reproducibly shared with `dput()`.

```
df = structure(list(Row = 1:10, A = c(1L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 3L), B = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L), C = c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 3L), D = c(3L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 
5L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L), E = c(1L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
3L)), .Names = c("Row", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Comment: Thank you!  This was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply compare all the columns against a single column and see if all the same

```
df[rowSums(df[-1] == df[, 1]) < (ncol(df) - 1), ]
#    A B C D E
# 1  1 1 2 3 1
# 2  4 1 2 3 5
# 5  4 4 2 3 4
# 6  2 1 3 5 2
# 8  3 2 5 3 3
# 9  2 1 2 2 4
# 10 3 3 3 2 3
```

Or just `df[rowSums(df == df[, 1]) < (ncol(df)), ]`

---

Or similarly, you can avoid matrix conversions all together and combine `Reduce` and `lapply`

```
df[!Reduce("&" , lapply(df, `==`, df[, 1])), ]
#    A B C D E
# 1  1 1 2 3 1
# 2  4 1 2 3 5
# 5  4 4 2 3 4
# 6  2 1 3 5 2
# 8  3 2 5 3 3
# 9  2 1 2 2 4
# 10 3 3 3 2 3
```